# Sending emails to a mailing list with Mailgun

Tags: node.js, mailgun

I am creating a personal app for email marketing/news letter/campaign, for this am using the Mailgun API with node.js and a simple HTML form to send emails.

As of now, sending emails is working fine when I give the "to"-address directly in my front part. But when I try to send to a mailing list, I encounter some issues.

I'm trying to send emails to a list which is already created in my Mailgun account.

My below post method is to send mails.

```
 app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var api_key = 'key-here';
    var domain = 'mydomin.in';
    var Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

    var mailgun = new Mailgun({ apiKey: api_key, domain: domain });

    var data = {
        from: req.body.myname + "<" + req.body.email + ">",
        to: req.body.to,                
        subject: req.body.subject,       
        text: req.body.plaintext,
        'o:tag': req.body.tag
    };
    console.log(req.body);

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function(error, body) {
        console.log(body);

        var list =  mailgun.lists(req.body.to);
        list.members().list(function (err, members) {
              // `members` is the list of members
              console.log(members);
            });

        if (error) {
            // email not sent
            res.render('index', { title: 'No Email', msg: 'Error. Something went wrong.', err: true })
        } else {
            // Yay!! Email sent
            res.render('index', { title: 'Sent Email', msg: 'Yay! Message successfully sent.', err: false })
        }
    });
});
```

In the code I mention my mailing list. What happens is when I hit send, it shows success as in the following image:

[image: this is what i got from my cmd]

Finally, here are some logs from the mailgun dashboard

[image]

Please point out what I did wrong and share your suggestions how to send emails to the list. My approach may be totally wrong, so any guidance will be appreciated.

NOTE: from my console.it shows "**thank you,the messages are in queue**". but am not receiving any mails yet. Many many thanks for any help.

Comment: `console.log(error)` ?

Comment: yes did that. it show 'undefined'. but i don't know why for what it has showing undefined..!!

Answer (score 0):

Official docs
https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258:

> If you're on the Free plan without credit card information present or using your sandbox domain for testing, you're restricted to sending just to Authorized Recipients.

[image: Mailgun Authorized Recipients]